# WPF/XAML Style TargetType="MenuItem" not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to show/hide the little check mark next to the menuitem's header in a contextmenu:
[image: Contextmenu menu items]

How can I manage that via `<Style TargetType="MenuItem">`. Somehow it does not work and I dont know why .-.

Here is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Duplicate}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Done}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
           </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<!--....-->

<DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <!-- .... -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Done" .../>
            <MenuItem Header="Duplicate" .../>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that ContextMenu's DataContext is set properly? It should automatically be inherited from the DataGrid, but the DataContext object should have the `Duplicate` and `Done` properties.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about that, but I also though it would inherited automatically.

Comment: Do you see any binding error mesages in the Visual Studo Output window when running your application in debugger and you open the context menu on the DataGrid?

Comment: @Clemens It does not break

Comment: I don't mean a breakpoint, just warning message in the Output Window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing **IsCheckable="True"**: `<MenuItem Header="Done" IsCheckable="True" .../>`

Comment: Ok then, try this: remove your <Style.Triggers> block, and add <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/> directly in your Style. Are your MenuItems checked now?